# How do I bring full html code from Django database to template?

Tags: django

so I have a full html code-from !Doctype to -stored in my Django database. I was hoping I could bring them as template, NOT as the raw content displayed on the screen. Here's my models.py

```
class NewsLetter(models.Model):
    title = CharField(max_length=10)
    content = TextField()
```

And in the content field, I have stored full html code. In my views.py,

```
from .models import NewsLetter

def letter(request, id):
    thisLetter = NewsLetter.objects.get(pk=id)
    return render(request, 'letter.html', {'thisLetter' : thisLetter}
```

and finally in my letter.html,

```
{{thisLetter.content}}
```

I do understand why it displays the full html code, not the content. But I have no idea on how to display content instead of raw html code.
I very much appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`safe`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) template flag

```
{{ thisLetter.content | safe }}
```

Ensure you really trust the HTML stored in your database though, otherwise you might run into nasty security issues (that's why HTML escaping is enabled by default).

Comment: I don't think that's gonna help him out, he says he has code from Doctype to the very end, or at least that's what I assume.

Comment: In such case there is no point in rendering a template, just return the content itself in [`HttpResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponse)

Comment: @michaeldel How do I do that when the html code is stored in my database?

Comment: @michaeldel Oh actually, that safe filter did work. I totally worked :)